# React Website problem : Relative path redirect on root "localhost"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, path, react-router-dom

I'm developing a portfolio website on react.

I didn't have any problem to develop my website on the dev server... Until I tried to build my app in production mode.

All is well working on the node dev server (localhost:8080), but When I open the dist/index.html on my local server (wamp on localhost/website_2018/dist/index.html), no medias are loaded anymore : the page is considered as an empty one by my app (with no existing path in router).

My website is located in a subfolder : localhost/website_2018/ but I need to write the entiere adress "localhost/website_2018/dist/index.html" to open it on my browser. After that, when I click on a link of my website menu, it automatically redirect me on just "localhost/" where my homepage appears, but still without medias.

I presume the problem come from the public path of my webpack configuration. 
I searched a lot of similar problems on internet, but didn't found a working reply...

*What I want is that the "/" to be interpreted as "localhost/website_2018/" and not just "localhost". All my files and scripts in my app are called with this relative "/".*

Here's my webpack config :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'svg-react-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
       jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: path.join(__dirname, "website_2018/"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  }
};
```

In case, here is my menu links :

```
            <div className="main">
                <Route render={({ location }) => (
                    <TransitionGroup>
                        <CSSTransition
                            key={location.key}
                            timeout={1500}
                            classNames="fade"
                        >
                            <Switch location={location}>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
                                <Route path="/projets" component={ProjectsPage}/>
                                <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </CSSTransition>
                    </TransitionGroup>
                )}/>
            </div>
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Thank you in advance,

N.

Comment: I use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and all I have to do is add `homepage: "website_2018"` to my `package.json`. How are you including scripts / media in your React app?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delay, I was busy on another projects. I tried to add this homepage parameter to my package.json, but nothing has changed. Media/script are included with relative path like "./medias/myimage.jpg".